# setInterval function in javascript stops executing after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am using setInterval to continuously send GET request to a node server for syncing 2 youtube embed players based on playerState. useEffect hook is used to call the setInterval function on mount. This setInterval calls controlPlayer function. I used console.log to test the code. controlPlayer function executes for a few seconds[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrNcm.png) and stops executing

```
const controlPlayer = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/getplayerstate');
      const res = data.playerState;
      if(res == 1) {
        player.playVideo();
        console.log(res);
      }
      else if(res == 2) {
        player.pauseVideo();
        console.log(res);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(controlPlayer, 1000);
  }, []);
```

I saw so many questions yet I don't know what is the problem. Can this be solved or is there any alternative logic?

Comment: your console.log statement are inside the `if` blocks which means they will execute conditionally; try adding a log statement before the `try` block.

Comment: may be your api stops responding due to errors or limitations

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` likely does not stop, but `res` has a value you have not covered yet.
You should implement an `else` as well, otherwise other values for `res` are not covered by your `console.log()` calls:

```js
      if(res == 1) {
        player.playVideo();
        console.log(res);
      }
      else if(res == 2) {
        player.pauseVideo();
        console.log(res);
      }
      else {
        console.log(res);
      }
```

But why make the `console.log` output conditional anyway?

```js
      console.log(res);

      if(res == 1) {
        player.playVideo();
      }
      else if(res == 2) {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }
```

As you can probably imagine this is also a nice use-case for a `switch` statement instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. setInterval function is not the issue here. Making the console.log conditional is my mistake. I did not think properly. I will add an else statement and try again.

Comment: Sure sometimes you overlook those simple mistakes. Good luck.

Comment: I added the else statement. Now, it just stops sending requests to the server i.e., the statements inside the try block are not executing but the console.log statement before the try block is working. Could you help me?

Comment: You can post another question here for that. It seems you just haven't implemented every possible value for `res`? Have you read the API? What is the console output? This is all too lengthy for a comments section. Please post your new problem as a new question.

Comment: Okay, I'll post a separate question. Thanks for the help.